# Python's quicksort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quick-sort

I was playing around with sorting methods, brushing up on my algorithms. I have made the following implementation of quicksort:

```
def quicksort(l):

    def inner_qs(list_, start, end):
        if end - start > 1:
            piv = list_[end - 1]
            aux_index = start
            for i in range(start, end):
                if list_[i] < piv or i == end - 1:
                    list_[aux_index], list_[i] = list_[i], list_[aux_index]
                    aux_index += 1
            pivot_position = aux_index - 1
            # left
            inner_qs(list_, start=start, end=pivot_position)
            # right
            inner_qs(list_, start=pivot_position + 1, end=end)

    l = l[:]
    inner_qs(l, 0, len(l))
    return l
```

Please, take a look at it.

Comment: I thought it was more suitable here, since I was asking for a code review ;-) But okay.

Comment: I have edited the post title and body. Could you please take a look at my post now? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You tested this and it throws a recursion error. This means it's not ready for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] and feel free to come back once it works.

Comment: Like every straightforward recursive implementation, yours needs recursion depth of n for an n element ordered input.